# Junit test with mouse click event

Tags: java, junit

I have a Jpanel that contain a JTabel and JTextField that display the value of the Jtable row when the row is clicked twice. the user can edit the  JTextField value than click a button to update once the button is click the updateUser method will be called. I am trying to write a JUnit test to test that the updateUser is updating user.
How can I perform double click on a specific table row to get the data displayed in the specified JTextField?

```
 public void updateUser(){

      String  id= txtid.getText();
      String  name =txtName.getText();
      String q = "UPDATE `user` SET `name`=? WHERE `id`=?";
        try{
             PreparedStatement ps = Login.con.prepareStatement(q);
             ps.setString(2, id);
             ps.setString(1, name);
             ps.executeUpdate();
             JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "User Updated");
            }catch(Exception eu){

                      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unittest should test the Unit, specefically the logical unit, in your case i would change the `updateUser()` method to:

`bool updateUser(String id, String name)`

which you can test then undependant from the GUI elements.
The `showConfirmDialog` can then be shown according to the return value of the updateUser method.